# Invalid Segment Alignment

Tags: ios, air, app-store, adobe, flash-builder

I'm trying to load an .ipa file (on mac using the application loader).
After few minutes i get an error message say
ERROR ITMS -9000 : "Invalid segment alignment".
My .ipa file was created with flash builder 4.6,
Flex sdk version 4.6 (build 23201)
Air version 15.
anyone face with this isuus ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a post on that: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1628933

Basically you still need to wait for a new Air SDK to be released to correct all the problems. A lot has happened on iOS and more will happen with the release of x64, let's see if Adobe keeps up.